# Dynamic array in classes c++ [SOVED]

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, int

I created a header file **polygon.h** and a **polygon.cpp**

polygon.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Polygon {
    protected:
        int numSides;
        int* sides;

    public:
        Polygon(int nSides);
        Polygon(const Polygon&);
        ~Polygon();

        int getNumOfSides();
        int perimeter(); // perimeter = hekef

        bool operator==(Polygon);
};
```

polygon.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polygon.h"

using namespace std;

Polygon::Polygon(int nSides) {
    this->numSides = nSides;
    this->sides = new int[nSides];

    if (nSides != 3 && nSides != 4)
    {
        cout << "Enter sides for polygon: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < nSides; i++)
            cin >> this->sides[i];
    }
};

Polygon::Polygon(const Polygon& other) {
    this->numSides = other.numSides;
    this->sides = new int[other.numSides];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->numSides; i++)
        this->sides[i] = other.sides[i];
};

Polygon::~Polygon() {
    delete [] this->sides;
};

int Polygon::getNumOfSides() {
    return this->numSides;
};

int Polygon::perimeter() {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->numSides; i++)
        sum += this->sides[i];

    return sum;
};

bool Polygon::operator==(Polygon other) {
    return (this->getNumOfSides() == other.getNumOfSides() && this->perimeter() == other.perimeter());
};
```

I'v created a Main file as well but it doesn't matter.

The problem is when I'm passing in for example into **numSides** the value 5 and the program should make from **sides** a new dynamic int array with 5 slots as for this example, but instead, while debugging it I find out that it creates only 1 slot as if it is just a regular integer and when I set in the 5 values into **sides** (as for this example with 5), **sides** ends up containing only the first value I have entered.

I will be happy if someone will help and even solve this problem :)

Comment: The debugger only knows that `sides` is a pointer, and doesn't know how many elements it points to.  If you use `std::vector` you'd be able to see all of the points.

Comment: Stating the obvious, `std::vector<int> sides;` rather than manual memory management would make this trivial, and as a bonus, eliminates the need for a `numSides` member as well. That said, you're usage from the "calling" code is relevant. It should be included in your question. You're also missing a copy-assignment operator, therefore introducing a recipe for a [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation. Things to work on.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t say what debugger you are using, but for Visual Studio you can manually edit the debugger entry to be:

```
<pointer>, <size>
```

So in this case you’d say:

```
sides, 5
```

See this page for more info:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/198953/how-to-expand-an-array-pointer-in-the-visual-c-debugger-watch-window

Answer (score 0):

As [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805907/dynamic-array-in-classes-c-soved/60806028#comment107581427_60805907) and [1201ProgramAlarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805907/dynamic-array-in-classes-c-soved/60806028#comment107581421_60805907) stated about std::vector in the comments above:

> The debugger only knows that `sides` is a pointer, and doesn't know how many elements it points to.  If you use `std::vector` you'd be able to see all of the points.
>
> Stating the obvious, `std::vector<int> sides;` rather than manual memory management would make this trivial, and as a bonus, eliminates the need for a `numSides` member as well. That said, you're usage from the "calling" code is relevant. It should be included in your question. You're also missing a copy-assignment operator, therefore introducing a recipe for a [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation. Things to work on.

The fact I didn't see all of the slots is because I'm used to c# and less working with pointers, and the int pointer was pointing on the start of the array.